# CSS Card ionic left div with description

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to get a card that looks like this:

[image]

What I have so far:

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start> <img src="img/marty-avatar.png"> </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
  </ion-item> <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi there, can you post some of the code you've written so far?

Comment: Someone will help you. But you must help yourself first. Try to solve it on your on and then share here what you have tried.

Comment: Yes: <ion-card>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="img/marty-avatar.png">
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
        </ion-item>

        <img src="img/advance-card-bttf.png">

        <ion-card-content>
          <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
        </ion-card-content>


      </ion-card>

Comment: can u share it as plain html css, so that we can see the ui design

Comment: it's better now ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ionic responsive grid:https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/responsive-grid/

See code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-i21sbi?file=pages/home/home.html

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-grid>
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
  <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg">
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start> <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"> </ion-avatar>
    <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
  </ion-item> 
  <ion-card-content>
    <p>Wait a minute. Wait a minute, Doc. Uhhh... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?! Whoa. This is heavy.</p>
  </ion-card-content>
  </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-card>
```

Comment: tell me for more help